Number of non-isomorphic abelian groups of order $1440$, containing an element of order $180$.
I have already shown that there are $14$ abelian groups of order $1440$, up to isomorphism. Now I want to determine how many of those $14$ abelian groups contain an element of order $180$.
I figured if we have $14$ non-isomorphic abelian groups, I might just use that any abelian group $G$ of finite order is isomorphic to exactly one:
$$G \cong \mathbb{Z}/d_1\mathbb{Z} \ \times \dots \times \mathbb{Z}/d_n\mathbb{Z} $$
where $d_1\vert d_2 \vert \dots \vert d_n$ and $d_1\geq 2$.
By my understanding we should have $14$ different chains of divisors, i.e. $d_1\vert d_2 \vert \dots \vert d_n$, since we have $14$ non-isomorphic abelian groups.
As I tried to write such divisor chains down, I was only able to come up with:
\begin{align} 1440 & , \ \ \operatorname{ord}\overline{8}=180  \\ 
2 \vert 720 &,\ \ \operatorname{ord}(\overline{0},\overline{4})=180 \\ 
3 \vert 480 & \\
4 \vert 360&,\ \operatorname{ord}(\overline{0},\overline{2})=180 \\
6 \vert 240& \\
12 \vert 120& \\
2 \vert 4 \vert  180&,\ \operatorname{ord}(\overline{0},\overline{0},\overline{1})=180 \\
2 \vert 6 \vert  120& \\
2 \vert 12 \vert  60& \\ \end{align}

These are $9$ in total, so pretty far of from $14$. Am I really just missing some, or is my conclusion just wrong?

Either way, by listing all $14$ possibilities I wanted to determine which of the $14$ groups contain an element of order $180$. I was able to find such element for some of the divisor chains, but I am not sure if I missed some. Generally I have the feeling that this isn't this most elegant way of solving this.

Is there any other way? Any hints are appreciated!

Post Answer Edit
As it has been stated in the comments, I missed the following divisor chains:
\begin{align} 2\vert 2 \vert 360 & , \ \ \operatorname{ord}(\overline{0},\overline{0},\overline{2})=180  \\ 
2 \vert 2 \vert 2 \vert 180 &,\ \ \operatorname{ord}(\overline{0},\overline{0},\overline{0},\overline{1})=180 \\ 
2 \vert 2 \vert 2 \vert 2 \vert 90 & \\
2 \vert 2 \vert 6 \vert 60& \\
2 \vert 2 \vert 2 \vert 6 \vert 30& \\
 \end{align}
Here we can cleary see, that exactly the divisor chains, or rather the corresponding direct sums (=direct products), which contain
$$\mathbb{Z}/180\mathbb{Z} \cong \mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z} \ \oplus \ \mathbb{Z}/9\mathbb{Z} \ \oplus \ \mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}$$
are clearly the ones containing an element of order $180$.

You are indeed missing a lot of possibilities. To give one example, $2|2|2|2|90$. You could make your life easier by first using the Chinese Remainder Theorem.

@anankElpis oh okay, I was assuming we need $d_1< \dots < d_n$,  could you please elaborate how the CRT can help?

@tychonovs-scholar In fact you must have the possibility of e.g. $d_1=d_2$; consider the simplest case $n=4$, where your two groups are $C_4$ ($4$) and $C_2\times C_2$ ($2|2$).

A different formulation of the Structure Theorem of finite abelian groups states that every such group can uniquely be written in the form $$\bigoplus_{p\text{ prime}}\bigoplus_{i=1}^{r_p}\mathbb Z/p^{n_{p,i}}\mathbb Z.$$ This is equivalent to the version cited by OP via a version of the Chinese Remainder Theorem. This formulation has the advantage that we can focus on each prime individually, and at least personally, I find it easier to work through options methodically in this form.

The existence of an element of order $180$ is equivalent to the existence of a cyclic subgroup of order $180$. Written in the above form, $$\mathbb Z/180\mathbb Z\cong\mathbb Z/4\mathbb Z\oplus\mathbb Z/9\mathbb Z\oplus\mathbb Z/\mathbb 5\mathbb Z.$$ Similarly, if $|G|=1440=2^5\cdot3^2\cdot5$, then $$G\cong\bigoplus_i\mathbb Z/2^{n_i}\mathbb Z\oplus\bigoplus_j\mathbb Z/3^{m_j}\mathbb Z\oplus\mathbb Z/5\mathbb Z$$ with $\sum_i n_i=5$ and $\sum_jm_j=2$. Since subgroups of direct sums are direct sums of subgroups, we can check each prime factor separately.
Clearly for $p=5$ everything works. For $p=3$, the options for $G$ are $\mathbb Z/9\mathbb Z$ or $\mathbb Z/3\mathbb Z\oplus\mathbb Z/3\mathbb Z$. Only the first options contains $\mathbb Z/9\mathbb Z$ as a subgroup. Finally, for $p=2$, we need $\mathbb Z/2^2\mathbb Z$ to be a subgroup of $\bigoplus_i\mathbb Z/2^{n_i}\mathbb Z$. So the only thing we have to avoid is that $n_i=1$ for all $i$. Thus we have to count all partitions of $5$ into positive integers, not all being $1$. That would be a tricky problem in general, but $5$ is small enough that we can list them all (sorted by the largest appearing summand): \begin{align}5&=5\\&=4+1\\&=3+2=3+1+1\\&=2+2+1=2+1+1+1,\end{align} which are $6$ options.
Finally, the total options for $G$ are calculated as the product of the number of options for each prime, in our case $6\cdot1\cdot1=6$. Therefore there are exactly $6$ abelian groups of order $1440$ that contain an element of order $180$.
